# How can I parse json to enum with typescript

Tags: json, typescript, enums

I have a json string like this.

```json
   {
     "type": "A",
     "desc": "AAA"
   }
or 
   { 
     "type": "B",
     "desc": "BBB"
   }
etc.
```

How can I use enum to parse it with typescript? I can do it like this, but how to handle with `desc` field?

```js
enum Type {
   A = "A",
   B = "B"
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need an object, not an enum

Comment: but i want to use `switch` to handle it in different case. if i use object how to implement it, like object { type: Type, desc: string }?

Comment: yes, exactly; then you can switch on `object.type` and handle the differing logic there

Comment: It would help if you show what you want to actually do with the data (e.g. your `switch` logic). There are a lot of ways to represent that snippet of JSON data, and without the program logic it's impossible to make a great suggestion that fits your case (because it's unknown).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a type. Something like this

```
type Item {
 type: "A" | "B";
 desc: string;
}
```

Comment: The `union type` in typescript is confusing me, I don't understand if it's a string object or a type

Comment: In this case the union helps to narrow down the possible strings. If you declare type: string then any string is assignable to type. If you declare it as type: "A" | "B" then only strings "A" and "B" assignable to type. If you try to assign "C" for instance TS will complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties are related, i.e. `type` fully defines the value of `desc`, you can create a union type like this:

```
type Item =
  { type: "A", desc: "AAA" } |
  { type: "B", desc: "BBB" };
```